# minimum number of days to reach destination | graph

Tags: algorithm, graph

Given a graph in which each node represents a city. Some cities are connected to each other through bidirectional roads. The length of each road is also given. Some of the cities have hotels. Given a start city and a destination city and a value K which represents the maximum distance that can be travelled by a person in one day, find the minimum number of days in which the person can reach his destination (or tell if it is impossible for the given K).
(Note : If the distance travelled in one day is exceeding K, the person can rest in the city which has a hotel in it, if there is no hotel in that city this implies you have to choose another path. Next day, the person can start from that city and the distance travelled get reset to 0).

Comment: This is Dijkstra with a twist, that is, possible end points are defined by a hotel being available there. What have you tried?

Comment: @LajosArpad These kind of "twists" tend to completely change the problem. Take for instance the "twist" of shortest path problem where you need to go through a certain set of nodes. This quickly becomes NP Hard (Traveling Salesman Problem). I am not saying it is the case here (otherwise that would have been an answer), but the "twist" is non trivial. Specifically, consider K=2 and you have 3 nodes `a,b,c` (all with hotels), with edges as: `w(a,b)=2, w(b,c)=2, w(a,c)=3`. Moving from `a` to `c` directly is the shortest path that Dijkstra's algorithm will return, but it's not a feasible solution.

Comment: OP: Can you share some limitations of the problem? How many cities are expected? How many hotels? What is the expected value of `K`?

Comment: @amit If my position was that this question is the exact same as 'gimme tha Dijkstra', then I would have said so. However, there is no attempt evidenced in the question to construct an algorithm, therefore I pointed out Dijkstra as a potential starting point of a thinking process, but **not** as the solution. It is perfectly understandable if someone fails doing this, but nobody will earn my help by posting this kind of question. At least some effort should be evidenced.

Comment: *"If the distance travelled in one day is exceeding K"*: this is confusing, as it seems to suggest a person *can* travel more than K in a day, but just has to rest *after* having done that. I suppose this should read *"If the intended travel on one day exceeds K"*, and that the traveller should rest *before* exceeding K?

Comment: Can you give an example graph that you have trouble with solving? Can you also come back to my previous comment?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with Dijkstra:

- lets say our dijkstra state is `{daysPassed, timeTravelled, vertexId}`
- initial state is `{0,0,startCity}` we add it to priority queue (sorted as tuples, min first)
- For each state in queue:
- try going to all neighboring cities (if `timeTravelled + edgeWeigth <= maxTravelTimePerDay`), state changes to `{daysPassed, timeTravelled + edgeWeight, neighbourId}`
- try to sleep in current city (if it has a hotel), state changes to `{daysPassed + 1, 0, vertexId}`
- Of course its not profitable to sleep in same hotel 2 times so we can additionally keep a boolean array indicating whether we slept in some hotel and only try to sleep in hotel once (on first time visiting vertex)
- if any time during algorithm we reach goal city `daysPassed` from state is the answer

Comment: This doesn't "feel" optimal to me (not saying that this is the case, just my gut). Can you provide an explanation or a sketch of a proof why it works?

Comment: timeTravelled is the total distance travelled? or it has been set to zero every time when looking for next neighboring node because you are comparing with maxTravelTimePerDay (which is k acc to question)?

Comment: @bucky, `timeTravelled` is the distance travelled in one day. You can see it gets reset in the 5th bullet point (middle value in the tuple).